# Recursive inheritance with variadic templates and inherited parameter problems

Tags: c++, inheritance, variadic-templates

If I use a chain of inheritance like the following example I could use vars from the deepest base without any problems:

```
    class A { public: int x; };
    class B : public A { };
    class C: public B { public: void Do() { cout << x << endl; } };
```

If I do the same with recursive variadic template classes I could not access my vars. Any idea how to access the vars and why I could not see my vars?

```
    template <class ...Parms>
    class Example;

    template <class Head, class ...Parms>
    class Example<Head, Parms...>: public Example<Parms...>
    {
    };

    template <>
    class Example<>
    {
        public:
        int x;
    };

    template <class ...Parms>
    class Last: public Example<Parms...>
    {
        void Do() { cout << x << endl; }
    };
```

Compile fails before any instance of the class is instantiated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` is a dependent name in this case, so you must access if as `this->x` (or bring it into scope by putting a using declaration in your class definition:

```
using Example<Params...>::x;
```

**EDIT**

The reason for this is discussed in [temp.res] in the standard. Basically: when the compiler is parsing your template, it sees just `x`. It has no way of knowing that `x` depends on the template's parameters (which it does in your case, because it comes from a base class which depends on them). Therefore, the compiler tries to resolve `x` using what it knows when parsing the template, and fails.

Writing `this->x` indicates that `x` refers to a member of the class; since a base class of your particular class depends on template parameters, the compiler knows it cannot resolve `x` when parsing the template, and will postpone the resolution until the template is instantiated. At that time, the template arguments are known.

The same holds true for `using Example<Params...>::x;`. That also tells the compiler that `x` depends on template parameters, and its resolution must be postponed to instanitation.

Comment: Ok, this->x work, but I must say: I don't understand the difference between accessing x and this->x for data members. Can anyone explain *why* this happens?